# Laravel one to Many Relationship, Integrity Constraint Violation error

Tags: laravel, eloquent, referential-integrity

I am trying to save one to many relation to database but I am getting Integrity Constraint Violation error.

When I use id as primary key the data gets saved successfully. But when I use custom primary key, then I get integrity constrain error.

My database structure is like Student can study in many institutes and institute can have many courses. The error is while saving the courses.
The error is as follows

```
Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'institute_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `courses` (`institute_id`, `course_level`, `course_ ▶"
```

My code to save the data is as follows.

```php
$instituteDetails = new Institute();
$instituteDetails->institute_name = $request->input("instituteName");
$instituteDetails->institute_location = $request->input("instituteLocation");
$instituteDetails->institute_phone1 = $request->input("institutePhone1");
$instituteDetails->institute_phone2 = $request->input("institutePhone2");
$instituteDetails->institute_email = $request->input("instituteEmail");

$courseDetails = new Course();
$courseDetails->course_level = $request->input("courseLevel");
$courseDetails->course_name = $request->input("courseName");
$courseDetails->course_fee = $request->input("courseFee");
$courseDetails->course_concession_fee = $request->input("courseConcessionFee");
$courseDetails->course_duration = $request->input("courseDuration");
$courseDetails->course_commencement_date = $request->input("courseCommencementDate");

//Save institute details first
$studentDetail->instituteDetails()->save($instituteDetails);

//Then save course details
$instituteDetails->courses()->save($courseDetails);
```

My model is as follows:-

```php
protected $primaryKey = 'institute_id';

public function student(){
    return $this->belongsTo("App\Model\Student");
}

public function courses(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Model\Course', 'institute_id', 'institute_id');
}
```

My course model is

```php
class Course extends Model
{
    //

    public function institute(){
        return $this->belongsTo("App\Model\Institute");
    }

}
```

I don't think making foreign key null is a good idea.

Comment: What's your Laravel version?

Comment: Its the latest version 5.6.21

Comment: What's the result of `dd($instituteDetails->institute_id);` after `->save($instituteDetails)`?

Comment: Sorry my bad. I saved course first and then institute. The above code was for updating the request. I miss read the code. Thanks for pointing out the error.